# Lebesgue's Measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ a measure with values in $[0,+\infty]$ and $f$ a measurable function. Then, $f \in L^{1}$ if and only if the  function $t\rightarrow \mu (x: |f(x)| > t)$ over $(0,+ \infty)$ is integrable with respect to Lebesgue's measure. Moreover

$\int_{X} |f(x)| d\mu (x) = \int^{\infty}_{0} \mu(x: |f(x)| >t ) dm(t).$

Comment: For this I consider $A_{t} = \mu\{x: |f(x) > t|\}$. But I can´t use this to gain an inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try writing the right side as
$$\int_0^\infty \int_X 1_{\{|f(x) > t|\}}\,d\mu(x)\,dm(t)$$
and change the order of integration.